# general javascript validation for all views in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a custom button panel which is to be displayed in each create view of an mvc4 application. When save is clicked, it should go to a general javascript function which validates the view/form and return the error in an alert as well on the view next to the field. All I've been able to get so far is:

**EDIT**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - COMIS</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/buttons.js") 
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/navigation.js")
</head>

   function global() {
   function () {
    $('a.button.positive').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();

    if (!form.validate()) {
        alert('validation error');
        return false;                
        }
        else {
            form.submit();
            alert('submitted');
             return true;
        }

    });
  }
  }
```

**This is a sample view:**

```
@model ....
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Create"; } 
@using(Html.BeginForm()) 
{ @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <form id="form" action="Create" onsubmit="return global()">
 <fieldset class="innerform">
 <div>
    <h2>
        Add a New Rate</h2>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    Period Start*
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Period_Start, "{0:yyyy MMM dd}", new { @id= "from" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Period_Start)
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="editor-label">
    Period End*
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Period_End, "{0:yyyy MMM dd}", new { @id = "to" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Period_End)
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="editor-label">
    Rate*
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tug_Rate) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tug_Rate)
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="button positive">
        <img width="16" height="16" src="../../Images/tick.png" alt="">
        Save </a>

       <a href="@Url.Content("~/TugRates/Index")" class="button negative">
        <img width="16" height="16" src="../../Images/cross.png" alt="">
        Cancel </a>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
 }
 @section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }



 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

I put a break point on the save in the respective controller, but it's not even hitting it. I'm not sure where I went wrong in my javascript. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please make fiddle in normal html and show us?

Comment: Makes no sense to attach a click handler within the submit event of form.  Click has already happened at that point so validation code will never run. Where are you initializing the validate() method?

Comment: As @charlietfl said, you should bind on submit event also, don't cancel the default event first, check if the form is not valid and cancel it, you need just one if to do that !!

Comment: @innodel I don't think you can make jsfiddle with the ASP code !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KeshiPeshi/9oboj8md/

thats the js - but its asp code. its just to illustrate the effect of the buttons etc and what i want to be able to do...

Comment: there is no `form` defined in demo and no `validate()` method either. Where are you getting this code from?

Comment: validate() is a jquery validation plugin 

http://jqueryvalidation.org/ and the form's id is to the top?

new to all this as the name suggests... kindly advise if possible where i'm going wrong so i can hopefully learn and make the necessary corrections...

Answer (score 0):

Your event need to be bind after the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.button.positive').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();

        if (!form.validate()) {
            alert('validation error');
            return false;                
        }
        else {
            form.submit();
            alert('submitted');
            return true;
        }

    });

});
```

If you want the bind to be global in some function. Call that function in the document.ready :

```
function BindSave() {
    $('a.button.positive').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();

        if (!form.validate()) {
            alert('validation error');
            return false;                
        }
        else {
            form.submit();
            alert('submitted');
            return true;
        }

    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    BindSave();
});
```

**Edit :**

Working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/9oboj8md/1/

**Edit :**

http://jsfiddle.net/9oboj8md/2/

The selector of the form should be like this :

```
$("#form")
```

Comment: the event is not even fiering ?

Comment: I modify the selector of the form

Comment: now it says: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

Comment: You need to use a plugin if you want to use validate : http://formvalidator.net/. To valid the form you can do $("#form").valid().

Comment: changed it to the above^ and its saying: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'valid'. See edit above on how i placed items in the head tag of my layout page..

Comment: You need to add a reference to the plugin. <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. With mvc you better use data annotation with unobrusive.

Comment: my bad ... well i don't know what to say. Make sure the reference is ok and that your javascript is inside script tag or in .js